# Why Realizing Instances node removes UVs?

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers, uv, geometry-nodes

I made a building using geometry nodes

[image: Having Textures but cant apply a modifier to save]

It has textures and works fine but when I try to apply Geometry Nodes,  Realize Instances Node makes building parts loose their UVs. 
How is it possible to apply modifier and keep UV at the same time?

[image: textures are gone]

Comment: Hi. How do you apply the texture? Do you have a set material node? and set material index node?
Please show the full node tree.

Comment: no, i don't have any texture node

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/zWCMOSu these objects already have textures in the old blender 2.9 no needed any texture nodes or realize instance so this is new and don't know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When realizing instances, their UVs are converted to an attribute with a name equal to the name of the UV Layer that the source object have:

[image]

In that image, *UVMap* is the uvs of geometry from instances, while *uv_map* is the uvs of the Mesh Grid generated in the Geometry Nodes.

The *UVMap* can be accessed with the Attribute node in the Material Nodes.

[image]

You will need to set the material of the instances to this new material with the *Set Material* node.

If you will use the same material for the roof, you need to merge the uv of the Mesh Grid with the realized instances uv, you can rename the uvs of the objects being instanced to uv_map:

[image]

Or you can merge in Geometry Nodes, we do that switching the field depending on if the geometry is from the grid:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you will use a different material for the roof, you don't need to merge the UVs, just set the material of the roof in Geometry Nodes before joining the geometry with the instances.

If you dont merge the UVs, and use a different material for the roof, you won't need to manipulate any attribute in Geometry Nodes:

[image]

The only thing you would need is use the *UVMap* attribute in the instances material:

[image]

Comment: I followed everything and nothing happened or maybe I am stupid

Comment: @GeorgeK. can you provide a blend file with the modifications you did using this answer? that way i can search for what went wrong.

Comment: https://we.tl/t-KouJcIVTWv

Comment: @GeorgeK. The reason it didn't work is that you created a new material on the object with Geometry nodes where the *uv* attribute is used, while in my answer i modified the material of the instances. If you want to use the new material you created, you need to apply it to the instances using a *Set Material* node. I think that using a separate material on the final object is a better idea compared to what I did, since modifying the material of the objects that will be instanced will make them show textures only with Geometry Nodes. I will edit the answer to use that material.

Comment: @GeorgeK. also, if you will use a different material for the roof, there's no need for merging UV's.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Is any possible way to export the house models with textures?

Comment: @GeorgeK. There is an answer on this forum which I can't remember that explains export file formats in detail, but I think the only export format that allows textures to be included to some extent is _glTF 2.0_

Comment: Probably this but  glTF 2.0 exporting uv_atribute and not real textures I need
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541