# Geometry Nodes Texture Export

Tags: texturing, uv, export, geometry-nodes

I made building with geometry nodes with textures [I asked how to apply textures on realize an instance](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264961/geometry-nodes-textures-realize-instance)

Now my question is how I can export the model with textures I am trying to export in unity but model don't have textures.

I don't know if I am explaining correctly

Blend file : https://we.tl/t-875Xpr9eCl

[image: How I give model textures]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: nothing changed after 6 Years?

Woah became such work older versions were applying and ready to go realize instance ruined everything –

Comment: Well that answer was edited and updated a couple of months ago, but it looks as if the main limitations are due to the export file formats themselves. The Blender manual has [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_fbx.html#id6) to say about missing features in the FBX format.

Comment: Don't get why devs made it so complicated it was working perfectly in 2.93 it was just applying modifier and textures were stayed after exporting